# Nest.js gracefully shutdown

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I enabled shutdown hooks at my bootstrap function. Also I subscribed on application shutdown hook at one of my modules:

```
public async onApplicationShutdown(signal): Promise<void>
{
   console.log({signal});
   ...
}
```

Now I can press `Ctrl+C` and read an excellent message at terminal. Then my resource release works correctly.

Also I want to close my app if db connection failed:

```
export class MyDbAccessImplementation {
   constructor() {
      this._pool = createPool(some);
      this._pool.query(`SELECT 'test' AS TEST`, (err) => {
         if (err !== null) {
            console.error(err);
            process.emit('SIGINT');
         }
      });
   }
}
```

But in this case my onApplicationShutdown method does not triggered on db connection error and the application closes instantly.

How I can trigger Nest.js application shutdown from its component?

Comment: Did you try lightship? - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightship

Comment: @pravindot17 very interesting package. thank you. i will learn it. but i try to find a built in nest.js solution

Comment: What are you using for your DB? I recently got bit in that Prisma hijacks the shutdown signal and kills the process before the nestjs hooks can fire.

Answer (score 12):

I believe your problem might be that your NestJS instance is not listening for shutdown events. You need to enable that behavior with `app.enableShutdownHooks()` in you bootstrap.

This is from their [Lifecycles Events](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#application-shutdown) guide:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Starts listening for shutdown hooks
  app.enableShutdownHooks();

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

Comment: I get Argument of type '"SIGINT"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"disconnect"'.ts(2345)

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth what's the line that gives that error?