# NestJS Application rebuild without affecting current running process

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2, node-cron

I am using NestJS cron in my REST API application but I have a question. How can I stop cron without interrupting the cron that are currently running todo a new build to apply new changes into the code? For Example:

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TasksService.name);

  @Cron('45 * * * * *')
  handleCron() {
    //Long running process code
  }
}
```

This code should run uninterrupted.
I am using PM2 for process management. Is there any way to apply new changes without restarting the application?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you could try storing a lock of sorts in cache while running a cron job and use a [shutdown hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892684/nest-js-gracefully-shutdown) to check if its released and wait it out